# Celery time/date error on Heroku?

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery

I'm tring to run a simple scheduled periodic task on a Django app on Heroku using Celery. It works locally and I can watch the task running with:

```
python manage.py celerybeat
```

But when I push to heroku and run:

```
heroku run pythonm manage.py celerybeat
```

I get:

```
 [2012-08-24 13:31:43,185: WARNING/MainProcess] __    -    ... __   -        _
    Configuration ->
        . broker -> django://localhost//
        . loader -> djcelery.loaders.DjangoLoader
        . scheduler -> djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler

        . logfile -> [stderr]@INFO
        . maxinterval -> 5.00 minutes (300s)
    [2012-08-24 13:31:43,186: INFO/MainProcess] Celerybeat: Starting...
    [2012-08-24 13:31:43,325: CRITICAL/MainProcess] 
celerybeat raised exception <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: 
TypeError("can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes",)
```

Snippet settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
    'gunicorn',
    'items',
    'djcelery', 
    'kombu.transport.django'
)


import djcelery
import djcelery.schedulers
djcelery.setup_loader()
BROKER_URL = "django://"
CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True
CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'America/New_York'
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"

TIME_ZONE = 'America/New_York'
```

Snippet tasks.py

```
from celery.task import PeriodicTask
from celery.registry import tasks
from datetime import timedelta
from datetime import datetime
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from celery.task import task, periodic_task
from celery.schedules import crontab
import time, datetime

@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour="*", minute="*", day_of_week="*"))
def test_task():
    print "TASK RUNNING"
```

Snippet requirements.txt

```
celery==2.5.5
django-celery==2.5.5
```

What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of the exact solution but I got around it by adding

```
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = False
```

to settings.py

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to Celery 3.0.7 which fixed a timezone related bug.

Comment: Unfortunately upgrading didn't help.

Comment: OK, I just fixed another timezone related issue.  I will release 3.0.8 later today, but in the mean time you can install from github like this:  `pip install -U http://github.com/celery/celery/zipball/3.0`